# Downloading a PDF file from server

Tags: java

I need to convert certain data to a pdf file. For this I have wriitten the following code which will save data in TablePdf.pdf in the server. (Here the pdf file is saved in C:\ directory)

```
public String generatePdf() throws Exception
{
Font font = FontFactory.getFont("Ms Dialog Light");
BaseFont pdfFont = font.getBaseFont();

// TODO Auto-generated method stub
HashMap inputMap = new HashMap();

inputMap.put(TableProperties.PDF_PATH, "c://TablePdf.pdf");
inputMap.put(TableProperties.PDF_TABLE_NAME, "Table");

inputMap.put(TableProperties.PDF_HEIGHT, "1000");
inputMap.put(TableProperties.PDF_WIDTH, "1500");

ArrayList<String> columnNameList = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> dataList = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> columnWidthList = new ArrayList<String>();

columnNameList.add("Col1");
columnNameList.add("Col2");
columnNameList.add("Col3");
columnNameList.add("Col4");
columnNameList.add("Col5");

columnWidthList.add("1");
columnWidthList.add("2");
columnWidthList.add("2");
columnWidthList.add("3");
columnWidthList.add("1");

for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
    dataList.add("Id" + i);
    dataList.add("Name is = " + Math.random() * i);
    dataList.add("Field Value1 is = " + Math.random() * i);
    dataList.add("Field Value2 is = " + Math.random() * i);
    dataList.add("Field Value3 is = " + Math.random() * i);
    }

inputMap.put(TableProperties.PDF_TABLE_COLUMN_NUMBER, "5");
inputMap.put(TableProperties.PDF_TABLE_COLUMN_NAME, columnNameList);
inputMap.put(TableProperties.PDF_TABLE_COLUMN_VALUES, dataList);

inputMap.put(TableProperties.PDF_TABLE_HEADER_WIDTH, columnWidthList);

inputMap.put(TableProperties.PDF_HEADER, "            Hello\n\n");
inputMap.put(TableProperties.PDF_HEADER_FONT_NAME, pdfFont);
inputMap.put(TableProperties.PDF_HEADER_FONT_SIZE, "20.0");
inputMap.put(TableProperties.PDF_HEADER_ALIGNMENT, Element.ALIGN_LEFT);

inputMap.put(TableProperties.PDF_FOOTER, "             Tata");
inputMap.put(TableProperties.PDF_FOOTER_FONT_NAME, pdfFont);
inputMap.put(TableProperties.PDF_FOOTER_FONT_SIZE, "9.0");
inputMap.put(TableProperties.PDF_FOOTER_ALIGNMENT, Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);

inputMap.put(TableProperties.PDF_TABLE_CELL_HEIGHT, "6.0");
inputMap.put(TableProperties.PDF_TABLE_HEADER_HEIGHT, "4.0");

inputMap.put(TableProperties.PDF_TABLE_ALTERNATE_BACKGROUND_COLOR, "Y");
inputMap.put(TableProperties.PDF_TABLE_BACKGROUND_COLOR, BaseColor.CYAN);
inputMap.put(TableProperties.PDF_TABLE_CELL_ALIGNMENT, new Integer(Element.ALIGN_LEFT));
inputMap.put(TableProperties.PDF_TABLE_FONT_NAME, pdfFont);
inputMap.put(TableProperties.PDF_TABLE_FONT_SIZE, "6.0");
inputMap.put(TableProperties.PDF_TABLE_HEADER_ALIGNMENT, new Integer(Element.ALIGN_CENTER));
inputMap.put(TableProperties.PDF_TABLE_HEADER_BACKGROUND_COLOR, BaseColor.GRAY);

inputMap.put(TableProperties.PDF_TABLE_HEADER_FONT_NAME, FontFactory.getFont("Times-Roman").getBaseFont());
inputMap.put(TableProperties.PDF_TABLE_HEADER_FONT_SIZE, "6.0");

CreateTable crtTbl = new CreateTable();
    crtTbl.createTable(inputMap);
}
```

Now I need to allow the client so that they can download the pdf file.

--------------------EDITED--------------------------------

Below is my jsp code to download the pdf file. Its giving no error in the console, but the file is not downloading.

```
<%@ page import="java.util.*,java.io.*"%>
<%@ page language="java"%>

<%
    try
    {

        response.setContentType ("application/pdf");    
        //set the header and also the Name by which user will be prompted to save
        response.setHeader ("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=TablePdf.pdf");

        File f = new File ("C:\\TablePdf.pdf");

        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(f);
        ServletOutputStream servletOutputStream = response.getOutputStream();
        int bit = 256;
        int i = 0;
        try 
        {

            while ((bit) >= 0) 
            {
                bit = inputStream.read();
                servletOutputStream.write(bit);
            }
            System.out.println("" +bit);


            }
            catch (Exception ioe) 
            {
                ioe.printStackTrace(System.out);
            }
            servletOutputStream.flush();
            //outs.close();
            inputStream.close();    
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }

%>
```

Comment: What is your server and what could be the clients ? btw the hole code you have posted here is not relevant for answering the question.

Answer (score 2):

There are many options. Two of them:

- Install a simple Apache server - you store the PDF files under htdocs, and they will be accessible
- Have tomcat (or another servlet container), and make a servlet that reads files from the directory they are stored and streams them for download. In short, this is done by transferring their bytes from the `FileInputStream` to the `response.getOutputStream()`. Also set the Content-Disposition` header accordingly

Comment: Searched a lot, but not able to find working example for file downloading. I am using tomcat.